# Built-In Data Frames With a Column of Times in the POSIXct Format

Tags: r

Is it possible to write a function that will search through R's repository of built-in data frames to determine if any contain a column of class POSIXct?

Comment: Column `time_hour` of the `flights` table in the  [nycflights13 package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nycflights13/index.html) contains scheduled date and hour of the flight as a POSIXct date.

Comment: `data()$results[,'Item']` will return the names of all installed datasets. You could loop through them, checking for variable types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like none of the built-in datasets have a POSIXct column. As @Uwe suggested above, **nycflights13** might be the way to go...

```r
# function to determine if a dataset has a POSIX.ct column
has_posixct <- function(data) {
  any(vapply(data, inherits, FUN.VALUE = logical(1), "POSIXct"))
}

has_posixct(mtcars)
#> [1] FALSE

has_posixct(nycflights13::flights)
#> [1] TRUE

# evaluates using name of dataset
has_posixct_name <- function(name) {
  data <- eval(as.symbol(name))
  has_posixct(data)
}

# names of built-in datasets
datanames <- ls("package:datasets")
str(datanames)
#>  chr [1:104] "ability.cov" "airmiles" "AirPassengers" "airquality" ...

# do any contain POSIXct?
any(vapply(datanames, has_posixct_name, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>